# How can I avoid Roomba Error 10 Code?

Tags: mobile-robot, irobot-create, roomba

I am trying to run my 600 series Roomba in a large, open space (1700+sf) and it does not recognize the large, open space and throws the Error 10 code.  It does not recognize an edge of 2 12"-3" either; it will fall off the edge and become stuck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"not recognizing the edge"*?  I don't know what *2 12"-3"* means.  Is this is cliff that the robot doesn't see?  Also, is this running the factory Roomba code (by you pressing the "Clean" button), or are you controlling the robot through the serial interface?

Answer (score 2):

iRobot's [home robot support page](http://homesupport.irobot.com/) has a [list of error codes](http://homesupport.irobot.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/641/p/3721) and specifies a few different [solutions for error code 10](http://homesupport.irobot.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7310/p/3721).

But simply: if your room is too big, use virtual walls.  And if your wheel is stuck, clear the debris.